# How to solve $\sin{x}=c \,x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find $x$ in the following equation, where $c$ is a known constant:

$\sin{x}= c \,x$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the [Newton-Raphson method](http://enwp.org/Newton-Raphson_method)?

Comment: I would say numerical approximation is the only way.

Comment: For $c\geq 1$ it is easy to find all the solutions explicitly.

Comment: Are you familiar with *trascendental equations*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no analytical solution for this kind of equations in which are miwed polynomials and trigonometric functions. Only numerical methods will do the job.

With regard to the equation in your post, you can consider that it reflects the intersection of $\sin(x)$ and the straight line $c x$. As you know, if $c \geq 1$, the only solution is $x=0$. So, we shall assume that $c \lt 1$.

A simple root-finding method is Newton, which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$ will updtae it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n- \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ So, for your case, $f(x)=\sin(x)-cx$.

For illustration purposes, let us consider the case where $c=\frac{1}{2}$. A quick look at the plot of the function reveals a root close to $2$; so let us set $x_0=2$ and apply the method. The successive iterates will then be $1.90100$, $1.89551$, $1.89549$ which is the solution for six significant figures.